# Remove all spaces after last character and before final dot

Tags: php, regex

I have some rar files which im using a PHP to extract the contents, However some of the files have a space just before the extension and i can't figure out how to remove it.

Example:

```
This is a file.name (Testing) .rar
```

I want to remove the space just after the ) and .rar but i don't want the remove any other like the one in file.name

Is this possible ?

Comment: doable with regex and `preg_replace`, but if it's always `.rar` then you can replace the last `" .rar"` (with a space) by `".rar"` (without a space)

Comment: have any of the proposed answers solved the problem? if yes, would you mind accepting/voting? http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex to match:

```
\s*(?=(?:\.[^.]+)?$)
```

And replace with `''` (empty string)

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sV3wZ5/7)

Answer (score 0):

Without regex:

```
$filename="This is a file.name (Testing) .rar";
if ($dot=strrpos($filename,".")) {
    $filename=trim(substr($filename,0,$dot)).substr($filename,$dot);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses a PCRE to replace the whitespace between the last non-whitespace character before the final dot and the final dot:

```
$filename = "This is a file.name (Testing) .rar";
echo preg_replace("/^(.*?)\s*(\.[^\s\.]+)$/", "\\1\\2", $filename);

// will output:   This is a file.name (Testing).rar
```

Limitation: the filename extension itself must not contain any whitespace.